# Using model trained in GCP for inferencing?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, image-segmentation, tpu, gcp-ai-platform-training

I'm new to this topic so please bear with me.

I've been following this tutorial to train my own model for segmentation: [ShapeMask on GCP](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tutorials/shapemask)
The training process completed successfully and I got the following output:

### [image]

Now, I'm trying to use this in the colab notebook provided by google: [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/tools/colab/shapemask_instance_segmentation.ipynb)

However I'm unable to provide my trained model to it. I require a saved model in that notebook however I had very little luck getting my output converted to saved model.I'm using TF version 1.15.2 on VM and TPU.

There are a few steps in between the training and inferencing that I am missing. But I dont know what they are. Any help is very appretiated. Thank You!

So far, I've tried to convert my files into a saved model using [this](https://gist.github.com/zhanwenchen/d628ef70e9f76525fd47d6213c30730d). And read thru [this](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/exporting-savedmodel-for-prediction) but could not understand how to make use of it.

Comment: could you be more specific on what particular step you get lost / get an error / get unexpected behaviour? in which part of te process are you stuck?

Comment: Sure, In that colab notebook I specified, if you go to cell 6 "Load the pretrained model", the tutorial loads model using 'tf.saved_model.loader.load' function. I want to provide my trained model output there and I couldnt figure out how.

Comment: @AlbertAlbesa Please check my answer below.. Would love any help or further clarification as I'm not expert on this! Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to kind of get to save model from checkpoints. Using the following snippet on a colab notebook. I had to enable TPU in the colab notebook (Runtime > Change Runtime Type > TPU) probably because I trined on TPU(It would throw an error otherwise).

```
import os
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
from google.protobuf import text_format
from tensorflow import keras

trained_checkpoint_prefix ='<GC storage bucket path>/model.ckpt-1000'
export_dir = '<GC storage bucket path>'
tpu_address = 'grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR']

graph = tf.Graph()
with tf.Session(target=tpu_address,graph=graph) as sess:
    # Reste from checkpoint
    loader = tf.train.import_meta_graph(trained_checkpoint_prefix + '.meta', clear_devices=True)
    loader.restore(sess, trained_checkpoint_prefix)
    # Export checkpoint to SavedModel
    builder = tf.compat.v1.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_dir)
    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess, [tf.saved_model.TRAINING, tf.saved_model.SERVING], strip_default_attrs=True)
    builder.save()
```

Now I say kind of because this saved model plugged into the Colab tutorial noteook doesnt work. It reads the model successfully in cell 6 but I get error with the inferencing part. Right here:

```
num_detections, detection_boxes, detection_classes, detection_scores, detection_masks, detection_outer_boxes, image_info = session.run(
['NumDetections:0', 'DetectionBoxes:0', 'DetectionClasses:0', 'DetectionScores:0', 'DetectionMasks:0', 'DetectionOuterBoxes:0', 'ImageInfo:0'],
feed_dict={'Placeholder:0': np_image_string})
```

The process ends with the following error:

```
KeyError: "The name 'Placeholder:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'Placeholder', does not exist in the graph."
```

It also cannot find all the other variable names. I'm not sure whats causing this and will update the answer once I do!

**EDIT1:**

I solved the isue using the following [readme](https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/models/official/detection/GETTING_STARTED.md).

First I used TF 2.2 and main branch of [TPU repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu) instead of the shapemask branch. Then followed the exact steps from original tutorial for training. And used the following command to export the saved model:

```
python ~/tpu/models/official/detection/export_saved_model.py \
--export_dir="${EXPORT_DIR?}" \
--checkpoint_path="${CHECKPOINT_PATH?}" \
--params_override="${PARAMS_OVERRIDE?}" \
--batch_size=${BATCH_SIZE?} \
--input_type="${INPUT_TYPE?}" \
--input_name="${INPUT_NAME?}" \
```

Here params override flag should be passed the params.yaml file created during training. Batch size is set to 1 for doing one image at a time. More details can be found in the readme file.

Note: I had to comment out the following line for it to execute:

```
import segmentation from serving
```

It exported the model and was able to load and use it in the colab notebook with some minute adjustments to the notebook.

Comment: What is the output of sess.graph.get_operations() ?

Comment: @AlbertAlbesa I'm not sure if I can share that data. But I did fix that error now. I updated the answer. Thank you for the help!